# HTTP load testing tool supporting TLS1.2/SNI

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https, performance-testing

Does anyone know HTTP load testing tool which support TLS1.2 and SNI?

I want to do performance test against Amazon API Gateway endpoint.
But this endpoint support only TLS1.2 and SNI.
httperf and JMeter currently does not support these method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://github.com/yandex/yandex-tank with patched phantom (https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom) as a load generator.

Simple, crude, hardcoded patch for https://github.com/yandex-load/phantom/blob/master/pd/ssl/bq_conn_ssl.C#L112 looks like https://gist.github.com/nnugumanov/90578be2e6a229e56ae1#file-gistfile1-txt-L3-L6

As phantom uses openssl for tls/ssl, tls 1.2 will be supported since you'll have installed proper openssl version.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler with StresStimulus add-on supports load testing over TLS1.2 with SNI. Install Fiddler 4 and [enable TLS1.2](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/fiddler-and-modern-tls-versions).  Then install [StresStimulus](http://www.stresstimulus.com/). Our free edition support up to 250 concurrent sessions.